# How to tell JavaScript to do nothing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small chunk of code, like this:

```
$("div.footerMenu li").click(
    function () {
        $("div.onScreen").hide();
        $(this).children("div.onScreen").fadeIn('fast');    
    },function(){
        $("div.onScreen").hide();
});//click
```

And when I click on `<li>` the div .onScreen shows nicely, but when i click on this div, that just showed up the functions is hiding in and showing again, but I don't want it to execute this function again. So my question is: How can I somehow "detach/exclude/hide" this div from Javascript?

**update:**

The thing is that with this method and with others with .one() the rest of menu is not working. There is the site with the problem [here](http://wujek-janek.com/fotozajac/) . I want this div that shows up stay there, when I click on it, but when I click on their items `<li>` I want to other div's (submenus) to show up (warning - big images on that site).

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="footerMenu"> <ul> <li>HOME<div class="onScreen"><div style="padding:50px;"><img src="fillTxt.png"></div></div></li> <li>PLENER<div class="onScreen"> <div style="padding:50px;"><img src="fillTxt2.png"></div></div> </li> <li>STUDIO<div class="onScreen"> <div style="padding:50px;"><img src="fillTxt.png"></div></div> </li> <li>INNE<div class="onScreen"> <div style="padding:50px;"><img src="fillTxt2.png"></div></div> </li> </ul> </div>
```

Comment: I edited your post because apparently you don't know the difference between Java and JavaScript. Unless of course you've forgotten to mention an interaction with a Java plug-in.

Comment: frankly speaking, you'r right, I do not know :( I hope someday this will change ;)

Comment: [You should probably read this then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java).

Comment: There are two functions being passed in to "click".  Are you sure you don't want "toggle" instead?

Comment: Please describe what your code is *supposed* to do, and post relevant HTML markup. I have a feeling that `bind/unbind` solutions are the wrong approach. **EDIT:** With regard to the update, which menus are you talking about? You have 2 sets on the page.

Comment: the bottom one on the left, with HOME PLENER etc.

Comment: @Szymon : I removed my answer since it irrelevant to the current state of the question. I propose a close and start all over? No offense but this gets a useless mess.

Comment: sure, i desribe it more clearly!

Comment: I really want to help you, and so do many others, but perjhaps you could post a NEW question in a NEW POST with a clearer description ;) (no offense)

Comment: Sure, i will do that right away ;)

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution is:

```
$('div.footerMenu li').unbind('click');
```

But should you have multiple click handlers on the selector, you may want to only remove one at a time. The way to do that is to store a reference to the function being passed:

```
function hideItem()
{
  ...code...
  //unbind the click event
  $(this).unbind('click', hideItem);
}

$('div.footerMenu li').click(hideItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle an event only once, you can use the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method:

```
$("div.footerMenu li").one("click", function() {
    $("div.onScreen").hide();
    $(this).children("div.onScreen").fadeIn("fast");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.one()`:

```
$("div.footerMenu li").one('click', function(){
    things_to_happen_only_once();
    // unbinding happens automatically
});
```